# Dynamic resizable background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the background image stick to the footer when resizing down. Feel free to use my code in an editor and replace the photos for reference. I'm basically trying to make the background image change in size dynamically with the footer and not be disproportionate. I wish I could post a video for visual representation. Here's my HTML and CSS code.

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: none;
}

#background {
  display: block;
  background-image: url("background_image.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 1213.5px;
  height: 700px;
}

#inner_body {
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 15px 0px 200px 0px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 100px 200px 200px 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.header {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header .top_menu {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2.5px 0px 2.5px 0px;
  position: relative;
  left: -70px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

#website_logo {
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  top: -3.5px;
  left: 170px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.nav_bar {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav_bar li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.nav_bar li:hover {
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #ff37f2;
}

#footer {
  background-size: contain;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 1213.5px;
  background-color: #ff37f2;
}

#h1 {
  margin: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#left_nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 170px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  left: 0px;
}

.side_text {
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: helvetica;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.side_text:hover {
  background-color: #ff37f2;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-radius: 45px;
  color: white;
}

#inner_nav {
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.text {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>WeebFreaks</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header class="header">
      <div id="website_logo">
        <a href="index.html"> <img id="website_logo" src="logo2.png" alt="website_logo"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="top_menu">
        <nav class="nav_bar">
          <a href="index.html" id="home">
            <li>groups</li>
          </a>
          <a href="index.html" id="home">
            <li>messages</li>
          </a>
          <a href="index.html" id="home">
            <li>home</li>
          </a>
          <a href="index.html" id="home">
            <li>posts</li>
          </a>
          <a href="index.html" id="home">
            <li>manga</li>
          </a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="left_nav">
      <nav id="inner_nav">
        <li> <a id="y_a" class="side_text" href="index.html">Your Account</a>
          <li> <a id="n_v" class="side_text" href="index.html">New groups</a></li>
          <li><a id="n_p" class="side_text" href="index.html">New Posts</a></li>
          <li> <a id="s_v" class="side_text" href="index.html">Saved groups</a></li>
          <li><a id="s_c" class="side_text" href="index.html">Saved Comments</a></li>
          <li><a id="s_p" class="side_text" href="index.html">Saved Posts</a></li>
          <li><a id="Friends" class="side_text" href="index.html">Friends</a></li>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="background">
    <div id="inner_body">
      <h1 id="h1">Website coming soon!</h1>
      <div id="p1">
        <p> there is no functionality in this website yet, so these links will not work,<br> please be patient because I want to get this out as fast and efficient as possible, thanks.</p>
      </div>
      <footer id="footer">
        <div class="bottom_menu">
          <nav class="nav_bar">
            <a href="index.html" id="home">
              <li>privacy</li>
            </a>
            <a href="index.html" id="home">
              <li>help</li>
            </a>
            <a href="index.html" id="home">
              <li>new anime!</li>
            </a>
            <a href="index.html" id="home">
              <li>new manga!</li>
            </a>
          </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Put the background image directly on the footer?

Answer (score 0):

There's too much in OP code (and a ton of styles that wasn't working) to get a good idea of layout which is necessary for a working solution. Basically I guessed as to how your webpage should be. The portion of styles that are most relevant to the question is:

```
/* Shorthand */
background: url(https://domain-name.top/path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
background-size: contain; 

/* Equivalent */
background-image: url(https://domain-name.top/path/to/image.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-size: contain;
```

**Reference:** [Background Shorthand](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background_shorthand.asp)
**Note:** Click the logo located at the top right side corner for the side menu.

```css
* {
  overflow: hidden;
}

footer,
nav,
label,
a,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font: 1.5ch/1 'Segoe UI';
}

main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header,
footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

header {
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 3;
  background: #fff;
}

footer {
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #ff37f2;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
}

.bar {
  display: table-colgroup;
}

.links {
  display: table-row;
}

.links li {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
}

a {
  display: block;
  min-width: 8ch;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff37f2;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #ff37f2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  display: block;
  min-width: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  object-fit: contain;
}

footer a {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #ff37f2;
  background: #fff;
}

.left {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  max-width: 30%;
  height: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu .links {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.menu .links li {
  display: block;
}

#switch:checked+.left {
  min-width: 20%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 30px);
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: url(https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/019/566/710/large/kate-kneebone-su-background-style.jpg?1564059648) no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px 20px 30px;
}

.content * {
  margin: reset;
  padding: reset;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3ch;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.75ch;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2.25ch;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Under Construction</title>
</head>

<body>

  <main>
    <header>
      <nav class="bar">
        <ul class='links'>
          <li><label for='switch'><img class='logo' src='https://4s10x0uwgv-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/graphic-design-logo.png'></label></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='_blank'>Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='_blank'>Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='_blank'>Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='_blank'>Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='_blank'>Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <input id='switch' type='checkbox' hidden>
    <section class='left'>
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class='links'>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>
    <section class='right'>
      <article class='content'>
        <h1>Monty Python and the Holy Grail</h1>
        <p>Burn her anyway! Where'd you get the coconuts? Did you dress her up like this? Did you dress her up like this? The Lady of the Lake, her arm clad in the purest shimmering samite, held aloft Excalibur from the bosom of the water, signifying by
          divine providence that I, Arthur, was to carry Excalibur. That is why I am your king.</p>
        <p>Bloody Peasant! No, no, no! Yes, yes. A bit. But she's got a wart. <strong> Why do you think that she is a witch?</strong> <em> It's only a model.</em> Burn her anyway!</p>
        <h2>How do you know she is a witch?</h2>
        <p>You can't expect to wield supreme power just 'cause some watery tart threw a sword at you! Well, what do you want? Well, Mercia's a temperate zone! Oh! Come and see the violence inherent in the system! Help, help, I'm being repressed!</p>
        <ol>
          <li>He hasn't got shit all over him.</li>
          <li>No, no, no! Yes, yes. A bit. But she's got a wart.</li>
          <li>Found them? In Mercia?! The coconut's tropical!</li>
        </ol>
        <h3>Burn her!</h3>
        <p>She looks like one. Well, how'd you become king, then? Shut up! Where'd you get the coconuts? Did you dress her up like this?</p>
        <ul>
          <li>The Knights Who Say Ni demand a sacrifice!</li>
          <li>And the hat. She's a witch!</li>
          <li>Shut up!</li>
        </ul>
        <p>I am your king. The swallow may fly south with the sun, and the house martin or the plover may seek warmer climes in winter, yet these are not strangers to our land. I have to push the pram a lot. The Knights Who Say Ni demand a sacrifice!</p>
        <p>Well, we did do the nose. Well, we did do the nose. And the hat. She's a witch! Who's that then? You don't vote for kings. Where'd you get the coconuts?</p>
        <p>Burn her! We want a shrubbery!! Knights of Ni, we are but simple travelers who seek the enchanter who lives beyond these woods. I dunno. Must be a king. On second thoughts, let's not go there. It is a silly place.</p>
        <p>Now, look here, my good man. Oh, ow! Well, I got better. Ni! Ni! Ni! Ni!</p>
        <p>Found them? In Mercia?! The coconut's tropical! Well, I didn't vote for you. What do you mean? She looks like one. Shut up!</p>
        <p>No, no, no! Yes, yes. A bit. But she's got a wart. Well, we did do the nose. On second thoughts, let's not go there. It is a silly place. Where'd you get the coconuts? I am your king.</p>
        <p>Well, what do you want? Who's that then? Now, look here, my good man. The nose? On second thoughts, let's not go there. It is a silly place. I don't want to talk to you no more, you empty-headed animal food trough water! I fart in your general
          direction! Your mother was a hamster and your father smelt of elderberries! Now leave before I am forced to taunt you a second time!</p>
        <p>I have to push the pram a lot. Listen. Strange women lying in ponds distributing swords is no basis for a system of government. Supreme executive power derives from a mandate from the masses, not from some farcical aquatic ceremony.</p>
        <p>I dunno. Must be a king. Did you dress her up like this? Ni! Ni! Ni! Ni! I am your king. Listen. Strange women lying in ponds distributing swords is no basis for a system of government. Supreme executive power derives from a mandate from the masses,
          not from some farcical aquatic ceremony.</p>
        <p>Did you dress her up like this? The Knights Who Say Ni demand a sacrifice! Now, look here, my good man. Why?</p>
        <p>Well, I didn't vote for you. Burn her! The nose? No, no, no! Yes, yes. A bit. But she's got a wart. The Lady of the Lake, her arm clad in the purest shimmering samite, held aloft Excalibur from the bosom of the water, signifying by divine providence
          that I, Arthur, was to carry Excalibur. That is why I am your king.</p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <nav class="bar">
        <ul class='links'>
          <li> <a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
          <li> <a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
          <li> <a href="about:blank" target='#'>Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='_blank'>Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='_blank'>Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="about:blank" target='_blank'>Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </footer>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```